# How would I store 3 values in one element of a list? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, list

for example I have a title, author and date, and I want to store this in only list[0] how would I do it?

Comment: Please provide an example of an input and a desired output.

Comment: Please give a minimal example and show us what you've tried so far. It looks like you either need a `list of lists` or a `list of dictionaries`

Comment: Store it as dictionary, OR create a named tuple OR class object with these properties

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a tuple and then assign it to list:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(('title', 'author', 'date'))
print(mylist[0])
```

Output:

```
('title', 'author', 'date')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2 solutions (but there are many more) :

If your variables are strings, you can concatenate them : `concatenated = title+author+data` and then incorporate them into your list : `my_list[0] =  concatenated`.

Or, more general solution, create a list containing your 3 variables : `my_3_variables = [title, author, date]` and then put this list at the first position of your other list : `my_list[0] = my_3_variables`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (a bit far fetched) would be to create a class with the aforementioned attributes and store each instance of this class in a list:

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title, author, date):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.date = date

    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join(["Title: " + self.title, "Author: " + self.author, "Date: " + self.date])

books = []
book1 = Book("title1", "author1", "date1")
book2 = Book("title2", "author2", "date2")
book3 = Book("title3", "author3", "date3")

books.append(book1)
books.append(book2)
books.append(book3)

print(books[0])
```

This will print:

```
Title: title1
Author: author1
Date: date1
```